# How to pause the app for a second, and display a popup with animation

Tags: android, animation, popup

In my app, I snap a picture, display it, and detect for faces.  Is there a way, for when the user hits the 'Detect Faces' button, for me to have the app delay for a few seconds, and have a popup box with the dialog: 'Detecting...' show up?  Also, can I get a tiny animation below it (like an hourglass, or a spinning circle)?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want, to simulate that the process of face detection is hard to achieve complex task, and you are doing it with a lot of vodoo code ?

Comment: Yeah - I want the user to think that it is doing a detection that lasts a few seconds rather than being instant.  The detection is done, I just want a nifty little animation written in dummy code....it won't actually be doing anything other than displaying to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found it in the API easily!  Was looking in the wrong place.

ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Dectecing...",
                true);

dialog.show;